# Javascript how to convert an anonym function to a named function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

Under my **Angular** app : 
i ve this template :

```
<dxi-column dataField="ordre"
              caption="Ordre"
              [width]="70"
              dataType="number"
              [allowEditing]="true">
     <dxi-validation-rule type="async"
              [validationCallback]="myFunction"
              message="">
     </dxi-validation-rule>
</dxi-column>
```

and **myFuntion**  looks like this :

```
  myFunction=(params) => {
    console.log(this.myClassVariable)
    return Of(!this.myClassVariable.includes(params.value)).toPromise()
  }
```

My purpose is to change "**myFunction**" declaration to be something like this :

```
myFunction() { 
  //SAME TREATMENT
}
```

Maybe also change the invocation in the html , but basically keep the same beahviour , 
 i ve tried this :

```
myFunction() { 
    console.log(this.myClassVariable)  // THROW UNDEFINED
    return Of(!this.myClassVariable.includes(params.value)).toPromise()    
}
```

but i got `UNDEFINED` for my class variable passing

**Suggestions ??**

Comment: Search for “difference between normal function and arrow function”, perhaps. There is no relevant difference between an anonymous function and a “named” function _of the same “kind”_.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/2864740 , https://levelup.gitconnected.com/arrow-function-vs-regular-function-in-javascript-b6337fb87032 , https://dmitripavlutin.com/differences-between-arrow-and-regular-functions/  , https://tech4grasp.com/difference-between-regular-function-and-arrow-function/

Comment: arrow functions don't rebind `this`.  methods and object literal functions rebind `this`.  console.log(this) and you'll see it's bound to the wrong object.  if you really want that syntax, save `let _this = this` in the outside scope and then use it within the method

Answer (score 0):

this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);

add this code in the constructor.